# How do I convert letters into numbers based on alphabets in r language?

Tags: r

Recently I have a problem to convert my dataframe. Now I have a data which some columns is the first letter of their name coded as number. For example, Anna coded as 1 due to her first letter of name is "A". Now, I want to change this number to letter in R. Is there any package or tools to help me finish that?

Another question is how to convert letters into their corresponding numbers?

Comment: Your screenshot shows letters not numbers ...?

Comment: The screenshot appears to have nothing in common with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **convert numbers into their correspnding letters** in the (English) alphabet:

```
nmb <- c(1,3,5,2,12,4,20)
LETTERS[nmb]
[1] "A" "C" "E" "B" "L" "D" "T"
```

LETTERS is a built-in constant in R. If you *subset* it based on the numbers you want to convert, you will get the corresponding letters.

**EDIT**:

If you want to **convert letters to numbers**, use `match` and `LETTERS`:

```
x <- c("A", "C", "B", "X", "K")
match(x, LETTERS)
[1]  1  3  2 24 11
```